# Unable to start mongod service

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, ulimit

I installed mongodb using the information in [this link](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-centos-6/). However, when I user the service mongod start command I get the following error. Can someone help me troubleshoot?

```
[Piyush@localhost ~]$ service mongod start
/etc/init.d/mongod: line 54: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/etc/init.d/mongod: line 56: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Starting mongod: runuser: using restricted shell /bin/false
runuser: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted
                                                           [FAILED]
[Piyush@localhost ~]$ sudo service mongod start
[sudo] password for Piyush: 
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

I tried using --repair command. I get the following output for that:

```
[Piyush@localhost ~]$ sudo mongod --repair
2014-09-24T00:05:06.089-0400 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2807 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=localhost.localdomain
2014-09-24T00:05:06.089-0400 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2014-09-24T00:05:06.089-0400 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2014-09-24T00:05:06.089-0400 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-09-24T00:05:06.089-0400 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-09-24T00:05:06.090-0400 [initandlisten] options: { repair: true }
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-09-24T00:05:06.106-0400 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-09-24T00:05:06.107-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-09-24T00:05:06.107-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

[EDIT 1]**_____________________________________________________________________________**

In the log file I see:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.2014-09-24T16-00-32
2014-09-24T11:54:23.636-0400 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-09-24T11:54:23.665-0400 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3004 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=localhost.localdomain
2014-09-24T11:54:23.665-0400 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2014-09-24T11:54:23.665-0400 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2014-09-24T11:54:23.665-0400 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-09-24T11:54:23.665-0400 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-09-24T11:54:23.665-0400 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2014-09-24T11:54:23.680-0400 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongo/journal
2014-09-24T11:54:23.680-0400 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-09-24T11:54:23.680-0400 [initandlisten] 
2014-09-24T11:54:23.680-0400 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2014-09-24T11:54:23.680-0400 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongo/journal or use --smallfiles
2014-09-24T11:54:23.680-0400 [initandlisten] 
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.681-0400 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2014-09-24T11:54:23.684-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-09-24T11:54:23.684-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `--repair` flag is meant to repair a corrupt database, not to solve any permission problems
2. You obviously didn't follow the instructions of the link too closely, because he did start the service as root. ;) `sudo` may only allow certain parts of the init scripts to be executed with superuser rights by the user calling it. Others *may* (though they shouldn't) silently fail. As for init scripts at least: sudo != being root.
3. To fix the problem: `sudo chown mongod -R /var/log/mongodb/ && sudo chown mongod -R /var/run/mongodb && sudo chown mongod -R /var/lib/mongo` Then become root and try to run mongo manually with `sudo -u mongod mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. In case there are other problems left, mongodb will tell you. Fix those until starting mongodb manually as written above works flawless, then use the initscript from that point on.

*Edit: corrected the --dbpath option as per comment*

Comment: Did you mean `sudo chown mongod -R /var/lib/mongo` in 3. ?

Comment: I changed that because it was giving an error and asking for more arguments. Also, when I try to run your second command I get `Error parsing command line: unknown option datadir`

Comment: If, however, I change to --dbpath I am getting the following output:
`sudo -u mongod mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
2014-09-24T12:00:32.831-0400 log file "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" exists; moved to "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.2014-09-24T16-00-32".`